# Can a relation be acyclic and complete but not transitive?

Tags: relations

I have come to understand that transitivity is a stronger condition  than acyclicity, and completeness and quasitransitivity together imply acyclicity. But is it true that acyclicity and completeness imply transitivity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true: $\def\R{\mathop{\mathrm R}}$

Let $\R\subseteq A\times A$ be an acyclic and complete relation. 
Suppose $a\R b$ and $b\R c$. If we don't have $a\R c$, then by completeness, $c\R a$ follows, but then this produces a cycle $a\R b\R c\R a$.

Comment: So the answer must be no. Since by completeness and absence of transitivity, we get a cycle.

Comment: If $R$ is complete and acyclic, then $R$ must be transitive (else $R$ wouldn't be acyclic).